# a:first-child over writing all of the <a> tags within parent <div>?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

```
   <header>
       <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="logo">Research Concepts | Satellite Antenna Controllers</a>
          <nav class="main-navigation">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link">Products/Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link">News/Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="search">Search</a></li>
             </ul>
          <a href="#" class="mobile-navigation">
             <div class="icon-bar"></div>
             <div class="icon-bar"></div>
             <div class="icon-bar"></div>
          </a>
       </nav>
    </div>
 </header> 


nav {
        float: right;

        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

            &:after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
                clear: both;
            }

            li {
                float: left;

                a {
                    margin-left: 2.813em;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    line-height: 36px;
                    color: $black;

                    &:hover {
                        color: $maroon;
                    }

                    &:first-child {
                        margin-left: 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong here. I've used the :first-child pseudo element before and had no problems with it overriding all the other elements like it is currently doing.

Here is the HTML that a couple of you requested. I hope that this helps.

Comment: can you post some html code as well?  its hard to tell if you are trying to do a `:first-child` when perhaps `:first-of-type` is more appropriate... proper context will help clarify

Comment: This code should override the first element contained in every <a> tag contained in the original <div> tag.

Comment: @Grapho I tried :first-of-type as well and it still did not work.

Comment: check your html. are all your tags closed?

Comment: Your logic is faulty.  If your `a` element is the only child of the `li` element, then it is *always* the first element.

Comment: post your code or put it in a fiddle.

Comment: yes we need to see the html please

Comment: Alright I have added the HTML

Comment: ok in this case, cimmanon is correct.  there is only one child inside of each `<li>` element, so they are all getting the `:first-child` properties.

Comment: As Grapho and cimmanon mentioned, your a is always the first element you need to add `li:first-of-type>a{...}` in your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already stated, all of your `a` elements are the first child of their parent element.  You need to select the first `li` element instead:

```
nav {
    float: right;

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        &:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        li {
            float: left;

            a {
                margin-left: 2.813em;
                text-decoration: none;
                line-height: 36px;
                color: $black;

                &:hover {
                    color: $maroon;
                }

                &:first-child {
                    color: green;
                }
            }

            &:first-child a {
              margin-left: 0;
              color: pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/37042db81ea407c76098

However, it would be more efficient to place the margin on the `li` instead.

```
nav {
    float: right;

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        &:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        li {
            float: left;

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                line-height: 36px;
                color: $black;

                &:hover {
                    color: $maroon;
                }
            }

            ~ li {
              margin-left: 2.813em;
              color: pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/2138cffab2129c5eded1